# How can I change the password used in netbeans to deploy an app to google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, deployment, change-password

Deployment of a Java application to Google App Engine from Netbeans 7.4 was rejected with the error message:

```
    com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: 
    Unable to update app: 
    Use an application-specific password instead of your regular account password. 
    See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833
    ... etc
```

I created an application-specific password... as explained in the link provided in the error message.
BUT I cannot find an option to change/replace the password I entered when Netbeans first prompted me for one when I began the application deployment process. :/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
I changed my regular account password and then re-ran the Netbeans "deploy to Google App Engine" function.
The error message changed - to indicate the password was wrong - and then provided a prompt with which to enter a new password.

I then entered an application specific password...

The deployment function then proceeded successfully.

It would be a good thing if Netbeans displayed the prompt for entering a new password when it gave the first error message: "Unable to update app: Use an application-specific password ..."